# Provision existing AWS lambda using Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform-provider-aws, cicd

I was learning terraform and was asked to provision it for CI/CD pipeline at gitlab.
My doubt is that ,

Let's say a lambda function is already running/live.
How can I provision it using terraform ?
Should I use data block to consume the running aws lambda?
Or this isn't how it works ! I am not sure how can we do this.
I searched the docs which isn't supporting this use case.

Answer (score 3):

So with the Lambda function that is already running, basically here you have two use cases:

- whether you want to add further changes/updates to that Lambda later on using Terraform. In this case, you need to import it to your terraform code, and all the changes you add to that Lambda can be deployed via your CI/CD pipeline, e.g.:

```
    terraform import aws_lambda_function.my_lambda existing_lambda_function_name
```

Note: Please note that the **my_lambda** function is your terraform block of code that is defining the exact Lambda that is already running, this is to match the existing resource with your code Terraform, to then be added to the state. I hope that it is clear

- or you simply just need some outputs of that Lambda to be used as inputs to other services, here you can simply just keep the Lambda up and running and use Terraform data source, e.g.:

```
    data "aws_lambda_function" "existing_lambda" {
      function_name = var.function_name
    }
```

And somewhere else in your code you can use it as follows:

```
    function_name = data.aws_lambda_function.existing_lambda
```

I hope this was helpful

Comment: So, it's like , say If I want to import any aws resource all I need to do is create a resource block and mention that block in my import statements ? Am I getting it correct. 

Example: for provisioning lambda , we also need IAM roles , for IAM roles 
All I need to do is , create resource blocks and then specify them in my import statements. Is it correct ?

Comment: @SuryaER by creating the resource block, you need to also specify all the configuration inside of that block that matches exactly the resource being created, so yes, you are getting it right. I know at first it sounds a bit confusing, but with practice, you will be able to do it more efficiently. 
What I suggest is to first start with understanding terraform import in detail, then start implementing your block of code that describes your existing lambda, then proceed with the import process.
If my above answer was helpful, please accept it, thank you

Comment: Your answer made things clear more than 100's of blogs online ngl and also If i want to import should I also specify all the details in resource block  or just I need to specify any resource blocks with required attributes and point it an import so terraform will take care of it ? Thank you

Comment: and also what about data block ? if we use data block then we aren't provisioning using terraform right ? only resource block provisions (create a resource)

Comment: data source blocks basically are used to retrieve for example the arn, name, id, etc of an existing resource external to Terraform, or even it can be used with resources that are created within the same infrastructure (for example you created a resource in a module, and you need to use it in another module: here you can either use outputs or data source to retrieve that information from the resource being created).
A conclusion from what I explained: data sources do not provision any resources, they are used to get information about existing resources. @SuryaER

Comment: And regarding the import, you have to introduce a new terraform resource block code (as if that function does not exist and you are going to create it from scratch using terraform). In this bloc, you have to copy the exact configuration of the existing Lambda, so that the import process can match the existing resource with the terraform code.
Please note that any difference in the configuration will result in either an error or creating another resource, and the import won't be succeeded.  @SuryaER I hope this is more clearer